# Create a CIFS/SMB server or create a userspace filesystem in Windows?

Tags: c++, filesystems, smb, cifs

We manage an legacy system from the early 80s. It is awkward to access the file system on it, and we're therefore thinking on methods to work with the files from Windows.

We have looked at two methods for doing this:

1. Create a user space file system (eg with [Callback File System](https://www.eldos.com/cbfs/)).

   - Looks to me like the best solution, but it is expensive
2. Create a [CIFS/SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) server to share the files on the network and mount using "[net use](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx)"

   - I'm not sure if this option even is possible
   - I have not found any good examples of how I write an SMB server. Maybe there's a reason for that?

**My questions are:**

1. Is the method two possible?
2. Is it possible to mount a CIFS/SMB share locally if there is no network connection?
3. What are the pros and cons of the two methods?

**Edit**

The legacy system runs under Windows in a house developed emulator (which works in much the same way as VMware). It is in this emulator we want to expand the functionality to distribute the file system in the legacy system to Windows.

The legacy system is totally unique. Both the operating system and file system is house developed (and very odd).

Comment: What platform do you want to access the Windows files from? Have you looked at Samba as an SMB server? http://www.samba.org

Comment: The files will be accessed from Windows. If I understand correctly, Samba is just for the Linux/Unix world?

Comment: Yes, Samba is for Unix/Linux etc. I am confused by your question still. What Operating System is your legacy system running? Are the files you want to access currently on the legacy system, and if so, what type of filesystem are they in?

Comment: FAT, FAT-32, NTFS, ext3 and HFS are all filesystems, or layouts on physical disk drive. SMB is network protocol that can be used to share FAT, FAT-32, NTFS, ext3 filesystems over a network. So your question about mounting if there is no network doesn't make sense - filesystems always HAVE to be mounted locally before they can be shared over a network.

Comment: I have written a little clarification in the question

Comment: The physical file system is located in the legacy system. So I thought that maybe I can share it on the network using SMB without having to mount it in Windows. So make it optional if I want to mount it locally in Windows, but still make it available to other Windows computers on your network

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42105/discussion-between-magol-and-mark-setchell)